# Loop through items and target first 3 and last items seperately

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach

Is there a better way to write this for loop?

1. I am basically looping through a collection of divs.  (The number of divs can increase and decrease dynamically, so it's never a set number).
2. If the length of the collection is greater than 4, I want to set flex styling the first 3 items.  And I want to set a width on the remaining items, from the 4th item on wards.
3. If the length of the collection is less than 4, I want to set flex styling on all items.

This works at the most basic level but wondered if there was a smarter way to write this?

```
let divCount = document.getElementsByClassName("luggage-tile-wrapper active");

for (let i = 0; i < divCount.length; i++) {
    if (divCount.length > 3) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            divCount[i].style.flex = "1 0 22.2%";
        };
        for (let i = 3; i < divCount.length; i++) {
            divCount[i].style.width = "145px";
        };
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < divCount.length; i++) {
            divCount[i].style.flex = "1 0 22.2%";
        };
    };
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: No need to loop at all. Stick a css class on the container indicating whether the collection length is greater or less than 4, then use nth-child to style the relevant elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do two loops, one for the first 3, the other for the rest. If there are less than 3 divs, the second loop won't do anything.

```
let first3 = Math.min(3, divCount.length); // don't go past the end if less than 3
for (let i = 0; i < first3; i++) {
    divCount[i].style.flex = "1 0 22.2%";
}
for (let i = 3; i < divCount.length; i++) {
    divCount[i].style.width = "145px";
}
```

Comment: Nice simple cleanup, thank you @barmar!

Comment: I wondered why you used Math.min?

Comment: To avoid going past the end of the array if it has less than 3 elements.

Answer (score 1):

So you always want to do

```
divCount[i].style.flex = "1 0 22.2%";
```

for the first 3 items

And for every other item you want

```
divCount[i].style.width = "145px";
```

So this is it

```
for (let i = 0; i < divCount.length; i++) {
  if (i < 3) {
    divCount[i].style.flex = "1 0 22.2%";
  } else {
    divCount[i].style.width = "145px";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already accepted an answer--and I realize I don't have all the information--but it seems like you could achieve this entirely in css, without any javascript at all.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > * {
  flex: 1 0 22.2%;
  background: skyblue;
}

.container > :nth-child(1n + 4) {
  background: pink;
  width: 145px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="luggage-tile-wrapper active">item</div>
  <div class="luggage-tile-wrapper active">item</div>
  <div class="luggage-tile-wrapper active">item</div>
  <div class="luggage-tile-wrapper active">item</div>
  <div class="luggage-tile-wrapper active">item</div>
  <div class="luggage-tile-wrapper active">item</div>
  <div class="luggage-tile-wrapper active">item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Ray, I did try this approach.  But I had an issue with (flex-grow/shrink).  EG -  in your example, let's says the width of the container is set, so only the blue containers, sit in a row of three, then the pink containers will wrap onto a second and third row.  But I don't want the last pink container to stretch.  I want it to keep the width set.  i believe it is not possible to achieve this.  To set particular widths for the blue containers.  Particular widths for the pink containers.  And prevent the last  pink containers from stretching. EG https://codepen.io/ReenaVerma1981/pen/BaPwQmJ

Comment: I still think it's doable. You could maybe set flex-grow on :last-child to 0? Have you considered CSS Grid? https://codepen.io/rayhatfield/pen/rNrGdKW

Comment: Hey @ray - no i didn't consider CSS grid. I always considered CSS flex to be the bible, but maybe I should research this :P. Thank you for your help and suggestions!  I will check out :last-child and grid :)